# Need help with sql update query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have table 'products' and I need to update 'price' field by 20% if product 'type' field is "imported".
How do I read and update field at the same time in my UPDATE query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that using the SQL's [`Update statement`](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm):

```
UPDATE products 
SET price = price * 1.2
WHERE type = 'Imported'
```

This will increase the `price` of all `imported` `products` by 20%.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

`UPDATE products SET price = (price * 1.2) WHERE type = 'imported'`